# Add CSS class to selected Wicket Tab

Tags: java, wicket

I have couple Wicket Tabs and I need to add CSS class ***"text-primary"*** to the current selected tab

```java
        List<ITab> tabList = new ArrayList<>();
        tabList.add(new AbstractTab(new Model<>("Tab 1")) {
            @Override
            public Panel getPanel(String panelId) {
                return new TabPanel1(panelId);
            }
        });
        tabList.add(new AbstractTab(new Model<>("Tab 2")) {
            @Override
            public Panel getPanel(String panelId) {
                return new TabPanel2(panelId);
            }
        });
        add(new AjaxTabbedPanel<>("tabs", tabList) {
            @Override
            protected WebMarkupContainer newLink(String linkId, int index) {
                AjaxFallbackLink<Void> link = new AjaxFallbackLink<>(linkId) {
                    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(Optional<AjaxRequestTarget> target) {
                        TabbedPanel<ITab> selectedTab = setSelectedTab(index);
                        ITab tab = tabList.get(index);
                        if (target.isPresent()) {

                            tab.getPanel(linkId);

                            target.get().add(selectedTab);
                        }
                        onAjaxUpdate(target);
                    }
                };
                link.add(AttributeAppender.append("class", "text-primary"));
                return link;
            }
        });
```

This is how looks like markup for the Link

```html
<a href="#" wicket:id="link"><span wicket:id="title">[[tab title]]</span></a>
```

this implementation adds to the both tabs css class and I need to check somehow if tab is selected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the passed argument `index` and compare it to the `selectedTab`:

```
if (index == getSelectedTab()) {
   link.add(AttributeAppender.append("class", "text-primary"));
}
```

Also take a look at `org.apache.wicket.extensions.markup.html.tabs.TabbedPanel#getSelectedTabCssClass()`

Comment: Thanks! I was actually wondering why there is no method TabbedPanel#setSelectedTabCssClass() it would be easier to set custom css class instead of current implementation

Comment: Because with a setter TabbedPanel will have to store the value into a field, and this will increase the Java Object size, both in memory and serialized.